# PHP pull data from array based on time

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
array(2) {
  ["Status"]=>
  string(3) "001"
  ["Data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["item"]=>
    array(87) {
      [0]=>
      array(36) {
        ["StartDate"]=>
        string(10) "2017-01-13"
        ["StartTime"]=>
        string(8) "07:02:18"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to basically selected data from it ONLY if the `StartTime` is in the last 30 seconds - according to server time.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: server time changed continuously. so sometime happen that some index will missed( means some data).

Comment: @Anant Absolutely. It's just this array will also change, so new entries will be added every few seconds and my script needs to find those added in the last 30 seconds based on the time on the server.

Comment: grab the time and date strings and use strtotime() then compare strtotime() against time()

Comment: @Chris Thank You, Chris. Will look into this.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk then go whith what chris suggested

Comment: @Anant Thanks, Anant! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getFilteredCallsByDate($calls, $since) {
    return new CallbackFilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($calls['Data']['item']), function ($call) use ($since) {
        return strtotime(sprintf('%s %s', $call['StartDate'], $call['StartTime'])) >= strtotime($since);
    });
}

$calls = [
    'Data' => [
        'item' => [
            ['StartDate' => '2017-01-15', 'StartTime' => '07:38:18'],
            ['StartDate' => '2017-01-15', 'StartTime' => '08:38:18'],
            ['StartDate' => '2017-01-15', 'StartTime' => '11:25:59'],
        ]
    ]
];

var_dump($calls);

echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");

foreach (getFilteredCallsByDate($calls, '-30 seconds') as $call) {
    var_dump($call);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function:

```
$out = array_filter(
    $values, // your original array
    function($element)
    {
        $current_time = time();

        // change the keys to match your input 
        $element_time = strtotime($element['start_date'] . 
                                  ' ' . 
                                  $element['start_time']);

        // fix this condition according to your needs
        return $current_time - $element_time < 30;
    }
);

// now $out contains filtered values and $values is unchanged
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, Yury. `StartTime` is in the format `07:02:18` so will this filter work for me? I have tried an example (changing one value in my array to be in the last 30 seconds, but I got a `NULL` output :(

Comment: Your `StartTime` is inside a nested array, make sure to use a full path to it. Also, you need to use `StartDate`. Use `var_dump` inside the function to see what are the values that it gets and compares

Comment: Aaaah, so `$element['start_date']` should be called something else?

Comment: Probably, `$element['Data']['item']['StartDate']`? It depends on your exact input.